# Prove that set of limits bound is open.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Consider the following problem: $\dot{x} = A(t) x$. Let $X_{A}(t,s)$ be the Cauchy operator of the following system. Let $M$ be the space of continuous functional matrices. Let's denote by:
$$
\rho(A, B) = \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}} \|A(t) - B(t)\|, \text{ where } A,B \in M 
$$
Let's consider the upper-limit function $\phi(A) = \underset{{t-s \to +\infty}}{\overline{\lim}} \dfrac{1}{t - s}\log\|X_A(t,s)\|$. We want to show that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ the set: $\{A\in M: \phi(A) < a\}$(i.e. Lyapunov's exponent is bounded with $a$) is open w.r.t. the metrics defined above.

I'was trying to use the simple definition of the openness in metric space (assume $a$ is fixed):
$$
B_{\epsilon} (A) \subset A, \text{ for } A \in M
$$
Which is equal to: $\exists B : \phi(A), \phi(B) < r$ and $\rho(A,B) < \epsilon$.

We can try to denote: $\{\phi(A) <a \} \sim \{A: \|X_A\| \sim e^{ r(t-s) + o(t-s)}\}$, but here I guess we need to use some more fundamental fact about $X_A$ (maybe continuous dependency on $A$).

UPD. We can consider the following problem as following. There is exists $Q(t) \in M$: $B(t) = A(t) + Q(t)$, $\rho(A,B) = \sup_t \|Q(t)\| < \epsilon$ and $\phi(A), \phi(B) < a$.

I thought about diagonal operator with small enough values on the diagonal (since I guess we can only consider the diagonal matrices).

Any hints?

Comment: What is the Cauchy operator, and the functional matrices ? It would be helpful if you provide some definitions, but if $\phi$ is continuous then your set is always open

Comment: well clearly $\phi$ is continuous if by the upper limit you mean the $\limsup$

Comment: @openspace If it's not a problem, could you please disclose where this problem comes from? The way I see it this is about the upper semicontinuity of the upper Lyapunov exponent, and I think one needs to be more explicit about the regularity assumptions.

Comment: On the other hand, there is an analogous statement in ergodic theory in autonomous discrete time; see Viana's book Lectures on Lyapunov Exponents, p. 151, Lem.9.1. In this setting uppersemicontinuity is an immediate consequence of the Furstenberg-Kesten Theorem.

Comment: I believe one can show the continuity of $A\mapsto |X_A(t,s)|$ for fixed $t$ and $s$; semicontinuity then follows immediately.